# Как получить переменную

Tags: javascript

```
function Alarm(clock) {
    Clock.call(this, clock);

    this.clock.querySelector('.set-alarm').onchange = () => {
        let timer = clock.querySelector('.set-alarm').value.split(':');
        let hour = timer[0];
        let minute = timer[1];
        let second = timer[2];
        this.newDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, hour, minute, second).getTime();

    };

    console.log(second);
}
```

как получить переменную second или this.newDate, чтобы можно было вывести в console.log?

Comment: Попробуйте так `console.log(this.newDate);`

Comment: В смысле "получить"? Вон она уже готовая, бери да выводи куда угодно.

Comment: не помогло.....

Comment: когда я пишу console.log(this.newDate) выводит undefined

Comment: потому что значения присваиваются только после вызова `onchange` события, а `console.log` вызываете сразу же

Answer (score 0):

console.log() внутри onchange и все должно работать или же какие то извраты с промисами/колбеками

```
this.clock.querySelector('.set-alarm').onchange = () => {
    let timer = clock.querySelector('.set-alarm').value.split(':');
    let hour = timer[0];
    let minute = timer[1];
    let second = timer[2];
    this.newDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, hour, minute, second).getTime();
    console.log(second);
};
```